# What is the best way of java socket server for TCP using by vert.x, netty, socket.io, or socketserver?

Tags: socket.io, netty, datainputstream, vert.x, dataoutputstream

I don't know what I have to use.
It's my first time to make Socket(TCP) Server.
I'll use java and eclipse platform.

I'm considering to develop Socket Server on the Eclipse.
**This server will be covered 500-2,000 client's connections.** 
(normally 1,000 to 1,500)
and the **data** which transfer between server and client is **sensitive and fast**.

The Server have to cover **'one second' processing with Send/Recv (transaction: 5-10 over)**.

**Questions>
What is best way to use the one?**

**Case 1>**
 `Original Java socket server
..... java.net.ServerSocket, java.net.Socket, java.io.DataInputStream, java.io.DataInputStream`

**Case 2>**
`Vert.X Framework
 ..... NetServer server = vertx.createNetServer();`

**Case 3>**
 `Netty, with Mina and Java`

**Case 4>**
 `Node.js, Socket.io`

**Case 5>**
`Question one more: is there any good idea for socket server(JAVA)?`

Sincerely,
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a scalable TCP based connection application, I would recommend either *Vert.x* or *Node.js*. I've used both of and I was fairly satisfied with the performance of both platforms.

Since you are going for a *Java* project, then the *Node.js* alternative should be discarded since your code source must be written in *JavaScript*, which keeps the *Vert.x* platform as your first to go choice (Don't forget that it is netty already under the hood so you would gain much of the performance optimization job done by the netty guys).